# How to change only a part of the state from child component react hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state, react-state

My parent component owns the state like this

```
 const [formData,setFormData]=useState({
        Basics:{
            job_title:'',
            job_type:null,
            ppo:true,
            emp_type:null,
            start_date_month:null,
            start_date_year:null,
            end_date_month:null,
            end_date_year:null
        },
        Details:{},
        Preferences:{},
        Colleges:{}
    })
```

I am passing the `Basics` object of the entire state as props to a child component. However, I only want the child component to have the ability to change the `Basics` object rather than the entire state which would not be possible if I directly passed `setFormData`

```
<Basics state={formData.Basics} setState={setFormData}/>
```

Is there a way I can pass only a part of `setFormData` to the child so that it cannot modify other properties of `formData`?

Comment: This is why you need to use spread object to update only state you want.
```
{...formData,Basics:yourNewData}
```
Generally good rule of thumb you have many states. Use useReducer for that

Comment: Thanks, that's basically what I'm doing right now! Can you provide an example of how to go about that using useReducer?

Comment: update with useReducer functionality

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure. Here it useReducer example:

```
import React from 'react';

const intialList = {
        Basics:{
            job_title:'',
            job_type:null,
            ppo:true,
            emp_type:null,
            start_date_month:null,
            start_date_year:null,
            end_date_month:null,
            end_date_year:null
        },
        Details:{},
        Preferences:{},
        Colleges:{}
    }
const formReducer = (state,action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
    case 'UPDATE_BASICS':
      return {...state,Basics:{
        ...state.Basics,...action.data
      }};
    case 'UNDO_TODO':
      return state.map(todo => {
        if (todo.id === action.id) {
          return { ...todo, complete: false };
        } else {
          return todo;
        }
      });
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

const App = () => {
  const [form, dispatch] = React.useReducer(
    formReducer,
    intialList
  );

  const updateBasicsInfo = _ => {
    dispatch({
      type: "UPDATE_BASICS",
      //You can set your form object its just dummy data
      data: {
            job_title:'Test' + Math.random(),
            job_type:"test",
            ppo:true,
            emp_type:"test",
            start_date_month:"test",
            start_date_year:null,
            end_date_month:null,
            end_date_year:null
        },
    });
  };

  return <>
  <div>
    Current job tiltle:{form.Basics.job_title}
  </div>
  //just dummy functionality to use reducer
  <button onClick={updateBasicsInfo}>
    Update job detail
  </button>
  </>
}

export default App;
```

Here is the demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-nfvktg

**Note:** Its only updating basics fields not any other field!

Comment: A lot of boilerplate for a simple task but yeah this does the job, thanks a lot! :)

Comment: yeah agree. But for lot of states, reducer make sense. In smaller project it doesn't make sense but in bigger project it makes sense(as your state object growing bigger and bigger)

Answer (score 0):

You could create a separate function that updates only that part, and pass that function instead of setFormData:

```
const setBasics = value => setFormData({
  ...formData,
  Basics: value
});

<Basics state={formData.Basics} setState={setBasics} />
```

You could generalize this idea further by passing the property to update as an argument:

```
const updateSection = (section, value) => setFormData({
  ...formData,
  [section]: value
});

<Basics
  state={formData.Basics}
  setState={(value) => updateSection('Basics', value)}
/>
```